# SWRevealViewController in ios giving bridging header error

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

My project using SWRevealViewController in ios was working fine before but when i copied it to a new location it was showing revealviewcontroller files missing error. I deleted both the files .m file and .h file. Then I added both the files again and also added the header file but I am still getting the following errors:

```
Showing Recent Issues
Bridging header '/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin-Bridging-Header.h' does not exist


Showing Recent Issues
CompileSwift normal i386 /Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/HeaderTableViewCell.swift
    cd /Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/ViewGrievancesViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/LeaveChild.swift" -primary-file "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/HeaderTableViewCell.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/ChildGrievanceTableViewCell.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/HedaerCellTableViewCell.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/Promotions.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/PromotionsViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/MdmShowViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/ViewLeavesViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/PromotionsTableViewCell.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/Constants.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/MdmReportViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/LoginViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/ShowMdmRowTableViewCell.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/UpdateViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/StringExtension.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/SpecialLeaveViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/ChildTableViewCell.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/ViewAttendanceViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/MenuViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/promotionsHeadTableViewCell.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/MenuHomeViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/AppDelegate.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/Mdm.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/LoggedInViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/GrievanceChild.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/RoutineLeaveViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/PersonalProfileViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/DataDiscrepancyViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/PromotionsChild.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/HeadTableViewCell.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/HeadGrievanceTableViewCell.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/jobProfileViewController.swift" "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/ApplyGrievanceViewController.swift" -target i386-apple-ios10.1 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.1.sdk -I /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire -F /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MBProgressHUD -F /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftyJSON -F /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Toast-Swift -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header "/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin-Bridging-Header.h" -module-cache-path /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D DEBUG -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Intermediates/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Intermediates/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/ePunjabStaffLogin-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Intermediates/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/ePunjabStaffLogin-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Intermediates/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/ePunjabStaffLogin-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Intermediates/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/ePunjabStaffLogin-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Intermediates/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/DerivedSources/i386 -Xcc -I/Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Intermediates/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc "-working-directory/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin" -emit-module-doc-path /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Intermediates/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Objects-normal/i386/HeaderTableViewCell~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name ePunjabStaffLogin -emit-module-path /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Intermediates/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Objects-normal/i386/HeaderTableViewCell~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Intermediates/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Objects-normal/i386/HeaderTableViewCell.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Intermediates/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Objects-normal/i386/HeaderTableViewCell.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Intermediates/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Objects-normal/i386/HeaderTableViewCell.swiftdeps -o /Users/rajvirsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePunjabStaffLogin-auseensntkpseucxkidususztofq/Build/Intermediates/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ePunjabStaffLogin.build/Objects-normal/i386/HeaderTableViewCell.o

<unknown>:0: error: bridging header '/Users/rajvirsingh/Desktop/drive/ios projects/ios dec 2016/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin-Bridging-Header.h' does not exist
```

Comment: your ePunjabStaffLogin-Bridging-Header.h "Bridging header path is missing ". pls check that and rest the path
In build settings.. in “Swift Compiler -Code Generation”—> Objective-C Bridging Header — “reset the Path of Bridging header file”

Comment: how to reset the path yaar?

Comment: “Swift Compiler -Code Generation”—> Objective-C Bridging Header 
add folderName/Bridging header file "
example:- ePunjabStaffLogin/ePunjabStaffLogin-Bridging-Header.h
and file should be at that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your ePunjabStaffLogin-Bridging-Header.h "Bridging header path is missing ". pls check that and rest the path In build settings.. in “Swift Compiler -Code Generation”—> Objective-C Bridging Header — “reset the Path of Bridging header file”